# What is the difference between pip installing a git repo with and without #egg=

Tags: python, git, pip

Both of the following commands successfully install my package without error.

`pip install git+https://path_to_repo/repo_name.git@v17.8.0`

`pip install git+https://path_to_repo/repo_name.git@v17.8.0#egg=repo_name`

What is the difference?

I'm using pip 7.1.0 and 9.0.1

Comment: @abccd: we found recently that it actually change the behaviour of pip. When `#egg=name` is used in that form or if it's not used, but the tag change, the code won't be updated when you run it second time (version won't be upgraded to new code). We found that you have to use `#egg=name==0.1.2` and this will "detect" code change and package will be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

***Working Out the Name and Version***

> For each candidate item, pip needs to know the project name and 
>   version. For wheels (identified by the .whl file extension) this can 
>   be obtained from the filename, as per the Wheel spec. For local 
>   directories, or explicitly specified sdist files, the setup.py 
>   egg_info command is used to determine the project metadata. For sdists
>   located via an index, the filename is parsed for the name and project 
>   version (this is in theory slightly less reliable than using the 
>   egg_info command, but avoids downloading and processing unnecessary 
>   numbers of files).

***Any URL may use the #egg=name syntax to explicitly state the project name.***

Comment: Do not use code blocks for quotes.  Among other issues, it makes screen readers read out the quote character by character instead of as words.